# Connecting to direct modem vs. router

Tags: wireless-networking

I am looking to get a work from home job which requires a direct connection to modem during work times.  I also use wifi for personal and home use.  Question is, would it work if I frequently switched between both.  For ex:  unplug wifi when I need to work online and connect computer directly to modem, and once I'm done, connect my router back?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it depends.

1. Some modems will only work with a single MAC address that has been registered in the modem.

   - When you change the connected device from the router to your PC (which have different MAC addresses) you may have to reset your modem to recognise the new MAC address (and repeat when you change back again).
2. Some ISPs register the MAC address within their own network. This MAC adress is used the "register" the internet connection when it is first connected (often by a "terms and conditions" page which you agree to on first connection).

   - If this is the case then you may have to call your ISP to additional MAC addresses to your account.

The only way to find out is to try it and see if it works.

Note that this question may be a [X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) question.

Why do you need to connect directly to the modem when working from home? What is stopping you from working while connected to the router?